# Should I avoid using a primary key and use an indexed, unique column?

Tags: oracle, indexing, primary-key, clustered-index

I have created a new table with no primary key. But the table does have one field which is unique and indexed.

This column is has got unique values and I can make it Primary.
But what kind of impact will be there be on SQL performance and what other factor will be affected if it's not primary?

Regards

Comment: To quote Joe Celko: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table*

Comment: Marc - I'm not certain of it but I think you may be misquoting or misinterpreting Celko. What he has said is that a table without a *key* is not a table (in relational terms). One of the things which Joe, Chris Date (and myself!) agree on is that of course a relational table by definition must have at least one Key but the idea of designating one key as a "primary" one is essentially superfluous. In Chris Date's words primary keys are "purely psychological" and therefore not essential however useful they might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the column may contain `NULL` values, then it cannot be a primary key.  In this case a unique index is the best you can do (note that this does not prevent there from being multiple rows with `NULL` values).

If it will never contain `NULL` values, then you should definitely either add a `NOT NULL` constraint on the column or make it the primary key.  Either way, this tells the optimizer that the column will never have `NULL` values, which allows it to consider some kinds of query optimizations that would otherwise not be possible.

I don't expect there would be any significant performance difference between (a) a primary key constraint, and (b) the combination of a unique index and a `NOT NULL` constraint.  Either way gives the optimizer the same information about the contents of the table.  Either can also be used as the target of a foreign key.  However, there are some specific features that require the existence of a primary key -- for example, an index-organized table must have one.

Comment: Thanks For Answering. Indexed-organized table : http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Index-organized_table

Answer (score 4):

A primary key can never be NULL, whereas a column with a UNIQUE constraint can be.

Answer (score 2):

A primary key is automatically unique and indexed. By avoiding a pkey you're basically reinventing the wheel and perhaps reducing performance as well. You should make it a primary key.

Basic rule of thumb for SQL table design and performance: Use what is readily available and don't try to out-think the thousands, perhaps millions, of engineering hours that went into creating such a robust RDBMS. For the vast majority of time the primary and foreign keys will be used properly and the query optimizer will pick the best execution scenario for you.

Comment: @Tony. Sort of. Index Organized Tables (IOTs) are close to SQL Server's clusted indexes, except the Oracle's IOTs always have the "clustered index" on the primary key where as SQL Server allows the clustered index to be a defined on any columns like a normal index.

Comment: @Tony: I assumed it would be a natural feature Oracle. There are ways apparently but it isn't by default like with SQL Server pkeys. Here's a link: http://www.dba-oracle.com/data_warehouse/clustered_index.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in principle or in practice between a "primary" candidate key and any other candidate key. The important thing is that a table should have constraints to enforce as many keys as are necessary to ensure the integrity of the data (at least one key). A primary key is only as useful or necessary as you choose to make it - although it is often very convenient for developers and other users to single out a particular key for some purpose or another.